# Express the following complex quantity in the form $a+bi$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently working on a problem and I need to simplify the following complex quantity in the form of $a+bi$. Assuming that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, here is the quantity:

$${(a+bi)\over (a-bi)}- {(a-bi)\over (a+bi)}$$

I've rationalized the left and the right terms and arrived at an answer of 
$\dfrac{4abi}{a^2 + b^2}$, but do not know where to go from here. I double checked my math and everything should be correct up to this point. What's the problem here?

Comment: Also, please tell me if the question is hard to read. The font may be a bit small.

Comment: Why do you think that you should be able to simplify further?

Comment: Well I don't see how else I can reduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $z=a+bi$ and want to compute
$$\frac{z}{\bar z}-\frac{\bar z } {z}$$
Where $\bar z= a-bi$. Combine denominators to get
$$\frac{z^2-\bar z^2}{z\bar z}$$
From which you get
$$\frac{4iab}{a^2+b^2}$$
So if you wanted to put this in the shape of a complex number $A+Bi$ you get that $A=0$ and $B=\frac{4ab}{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: Okay I understand that but can you briefly explain why A = 0?

Comment: @Oliver821 complex numbers can be expressed, as you said, as$A+Bi$ where $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$ and $i^2=-1$. $0$ is a real number and so is $\frac{4ab}{a^2+b^2}$ since both $a$ and $b$ are real numbers (multiplication of real numbers yields a real and division of two real numbers where the denominator is not zero yields another real). So both $A=0$ and $B=\frac{4ab}{a^2+b^2}$ satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Now I see it! Thanks for the explanation.